# Trouble passing an array to another class

Tags: java, arrays, class

Ive been practicing swing by adding a class that makes a GUI to one of the programs I made. Im currently having trouble sending my array over to the Visual class.

What I'm trying to accomplish right now is for the actionlistener on the button to run and change the label to the output of a random element of the array in the `EightBall` class.

My problem lies with me not knowing how to send over my array and random object over to it.

How do I pass the info to the `actionPerformed` method so that I can access `Answers` and `rnd` from the `print` method?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class EightBall {    
  public void print() {
 Scanner Scan = new Scanner(System.in);
 System.out.print("What is your question?");
 String question = Scan.next(); 

String [] Answers;
Answers = new String [8];
Answers[0] = "Unlikely";
Answers[1] = "Positive";
Answers[2] = "Yes";
Answers[3] = "No";
Answers[4] = "Ask Again Later";
Answers[5] = "Maybe";
Answers[6] = "ugh";
Answers[7] = "blag";
int rnd = new Random().nextInt(Answers.length); }
```

}

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing. *;
 public  class Visual extends EightBall implements ActionListener {
 JTextField textField;
JButton button;
 JLabel label;
 public static void main(String[]args) {
    Visual vis = new Visual();
    vis.go();
}   
        public void go(){

            EightBall ball = new EightBall();
            label = new JLabel("Whate is you question?");
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        button = new JButton("Ask");
        textField = new JTextField(20);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    panel.add(label);
    panel.add(textField);
    panel.add(button);
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setTitle("Magic Eight Ball");
    frame.setSize(1000,1000);
    button.addActionListener(this);
        }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        EightBall eight = new EightBall();
        eight.print();
        label.setText();
}
    }
```

Comment: You need to return a `String` in your `EightBall.print()` method then you can assign it to the `JLabel.setText(String)` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `print()` method in your `EightBall` class to return a `String` so that you can use the pertinent data in other classes. Like so:

```
public String print(){
    //your code
    return Answers[rnd];
}
```

This way you can access it in your `actionPerformed(ActionEvent)` method. Like so:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {;
    label.setText(new EightBall().print());
}
```

P.S. java convention is camelCase for fields/local variables (`Answers` should be `answers`, `Scan` should be `scan`)